# What is this style of instantiating a constructor method?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've seen this but I can't find the style anywhere, is this an immediately invoked constructor?

```
var Router = new (Backbone.Router.extend({ //... }));
```

Comment: `initialize` method will be fired immediately, Router variable will become an instance of this Router

Comment: Whats this style called though, immediately instantiated constructor, immediately invoked constructor etc etc?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression do you mean `IIFE`?

Comment: This is not Immediately Invoked Function Expression. IIFE would look like (function myIffe(){})(); 

Backbone.Router.extend returns a function which is called a constructor function. Constructor function when invoked with new operator, creates a new object, invokes the function with its 'this' set to the new object and returns the new object. 

Don't know Backbone but I am assuming, the object that is constructed by invoking the constructor function returned by Backbone.Router.extend() prototypically inherits from the Router object, therefore making all Router methods available to the object.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.

It's equivalent to:

```
var RouterModel = Backbone.Router.extend({ ... });
var Router = new RouterModel();
```

In other words, it performs the `extend` to create a function, which is then used as a constructor for object creation.